# Unite several HDDs without wiping them

Tags: linux, lvm

I have several HDDs (4x2TB) and almost every one is full of things that I have no time to manage right now.

Meanwhile, I have a planned project that might need tons of storage for several weeks or so, so I would like to use the free space spread over those drives and make as little changes to my current drive setup as possible - no partitioning.

I was thinking about creating virtual disk drives on each physical disk to delete them when the project is over.

Is it possible to unite virtual disks in an lvm-like fashion to increase performance and make things neater by not having to remember which file is where?

Comment: like this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_RAID_and_LVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very interesting alternative could be partitioning with Btrfs:
https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices

Quick and dirty solution in some steps:

1. Create a big file in each disk, using the free space you have (can be different sizes): file1.img, file2.img, ..., fileN.img.
2. Create one Btrfs partition using all the files as virtual devices:

   > mkfs.btrfs file1.img file2.img ... fileN.img
3. Create virtual partitions:

   > losetup /dev/loop0 file1.img
   >
   > losetup /dev/loop1 file2.img
   >
   > ...
   >
   > losetup /dev/loopN fileN.img
4. Mount the partition. You only have to specify one of them:

   > mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/btrfs
5. Enjoy

Comment: +1 I did it on Debian Jessie few weeks ago. I merged one partition on a physical device with several files located elsewhere into single btrfs filesystem.